# Determinant of a matrix and its basis

Tags: determinant, matrix-calculus

Is the determinant of a matrix independent of the basis in which that matrix is expressed? For example, when expressing in matrix form a quantum mechanics operator, or when comparing the same matrix but in its diagonal form.

Every case I try, I find it is independent of the basis. But why? How can I prove it, or what counter example could I find?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a consequence of Binet's theorem: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det (B)$. Therefore \begin{align}\det(PAP^{-1})&=\det (P)\det(A)\det(P^{-1})=\det(P)\det(P^{-1})\det(A)=\\&=\det(I_n)\det(A)=\det (A)\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A linear transformation from a (finite dimensional) vector space to itself has a determinant. Once you put a coordinate system on your space this linear transformation also has a matrix representation. You can use the entries of this matrix and a certain formula to calculate the determinant of the linear transformation (we call this "the determinant of the matrix", but most of the time that's a red herring).

The determinant was there before the coordinate system, and thus the determinant cannot in any conceivable way depend on the coordinate system.

Comment: I can see a point being made for e.g. change-of-basis matrices having genuine matrix-determinants rather than linear-transformation-determinants, as they don't exist until you impose at least two coordinate systems on your space, and they don't really represent an actual geometric linear transformation. But then again, their determinants always cancel eachother out as pointed out in the other answer (and as they should according to my answer, otherwise something has gone terribly wrong). So you rarely have to actually deal with those determinants.

Comment: Also, many applications of matrices have square matrices that don't appear from linear transformations (like the adjacency matrices of graphs). There too you could argue that the matrix itself has a determinant, rather than inheriting one. But in pure linear algebra, I prefer to think as much geometry and as little arithmetic as possible, and thus we arrive at this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is a nice way of seeing it